# How can one check compatible routes in laravel after one has already found a compatible route one doesn't want to use?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create some kind of Content Management System using laravel. Specifically, what I did is to make it so the user (admin or anyone who has access to the back-end) can create a route that is unique in the back-end and create the page content for that route (also choose the view that will display the page) without having to modify the routes/web.php file, since the route is saved in the database.

To make that happen ; I added a pattern route in the `boot` function of the `RouteServiceProvider` class like so:

**code-listing-1**:

```
namespace App\Providers;

//...

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            
            Route::pattern('route', '([a-zA-z0-9-]+/*)+');

            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        });
    }

    //...
}
```

and created a route in the routes/web.php file like so :

**code-listing-2**:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


use App\Http\Controllers\Page;

//home route somewhere around here

Route::get('/{route}', [Page::class, 'getPage']);//route that will be called when typing anything in the address bar
```

What I don't know is how to do is calling back the routing mechanism if no matching route is found on the database. I need to be able to do that because this will allow me to use other Controllers for other "plugins" I might add to the CMS.

Basically what I want to do is allow most non developer to create the routes they need for the site (without messing with the routes/web.php script) and for the developer to extends the app by creating Controllers that could be accessed through their given routes (listed either inside the routes/web.php script or, any of the laravel core php script or an external script if the solution to solve this issue needs one).

I'm thinking maybe

1. I should call the routing mechanism inside the Controller that is called by the pattern route if no corresponding route was found in the database or
2. I should write some extra code in the `boot` function of the `RouteServiceProvider` class that will force checking the remaining routes in the routes/web.php script.

I'm not sure what to write and where to write it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good night sleep solved my issue. There is actually a simple solution for this.
I added a 'web' middleware route in the `boot` function of the `RouteServiceProvider` class like so:

**code-listing-1: RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;

//...

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            
            Route::pattern('route', '([a-zA-z0-9-]+/*)+');

            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/patternedroutes.php'));

        });
    }
}
```

one should make sure that the script containing the normal (usual) laravel routes is above the script containing the patterned routes.

then I created a new script file named patternedroutes.php in the routes directory, remove the patterned route from routes/web.php and paste it in routes/patternedroutes.php. so that both script look like so:

**code-listing-2: web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**code-listing-3: patternedroutes.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\Page;

Route::get('/{route}', [Page::class, 'getPage']);
```